# Join statement returning duplicates to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following code:

```
 var selord = from x in db.tabOrderItems
                         join y in db.tabStockLedgers
                         on x.ItemSKU equals y.ItemSKU
                         where x.Email == emailadd
                         where x.OrderOutstandingValue > 0
                         select new
                         {
                             Order = x.OrderId,
                             Product = x.ItemName,
                             Date = x.OrderDate,
                             InStock = y.BatchBalance,
                             Unit = x.UOM,
                             Quantity = x.Quantity,

                             Price = x.SellingRate,

                             Batch = x.BatchCode,
                             Grade = x.Grade,
                             Warehouse = x.Warehouse

                         };
```

What I'm doing is showing orders and then getting the BatchBalance from another table. But the query seems to return every item of each type from the tabOrderItems table for the where clauses. On removing the join, data is fine but I cannot access the Balance. Can anyone help me with this? What is wrong with the join?

Comment: If an `x` from `tabOrderItems` has multiple matching `y` in `tabStockLedgers` than you will get multiple copies of `x`. Is that possible?

Comment: Thats what I thought, but the actual data is reliable, ie for each customer order we ensure you have just one item (unique batch number) so this we are checking using the email. In adding the order we use the email and ensure its just one possible entry for one batch of the item per customer. The issue is just in pulling a list to display in the grid, we need to show the actual stock to allow user update the quantity.

Comment: Any one have any ideas?

Comment: The query looks just fine to me and if you're right with the data constraint, it will return only one record per user email. Now, the result is slightly different so you should double-check the data from table `tabOrderItems` grouped by Email and see what is the result in return.